# Moderator election score

Tags: discussion, election

During the 2015 **StackOverflow** [community moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) (this is **not** about a moderator election on Unix & Linux), the candidates have a moderator score attached to their application, showing a number of points out of 40 based on:

- reputation 1 point per 1K rep (max 20)
- moderation badges: max 8
- editing badges: max 6
- participation badges: max 6

The detailed description for this is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289473/1307905candidate-score-badge-breakdown).

Even people not aspiring to become moderator might be interested how their score on U&L would be can put their user id in [this
query](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/edit/298739)

Would it be useful to have this on a future moderator election on U&L (and I hope that that will be a far-far away future)?

Answer (score 3):

Reviewing the previous two elections ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/1) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/2?tab=election)), it looks to me that this has been retroactively added as not all the necessary badges that are counted have been available at that time.

Chances are good, this will be done as well if and when a future election on U&L is held.